# How to get gtk.CellRendererText() column as a password type(*) in pygtk

Tags: python, python-2.7, treeview, gtk, pygtk

I have created TreeView() table with pygtk in my script. In that one column textbox is as password type and if I type password it is showing character but password should be confidential. so  I want, when I type password it show me just like as  invisible (***).

My code is written below

```
    #   columns
    (
      COLUMN_EDITABLE,
      COLUMN_USER,
      COLUMN_PSW,
    ) = range(3)
    model = gtk.ListStore(
       gobject.TYPE_BOOLEAN,
       gobject.TYPE_STRING,
       gobject.TYPE_STRING,
    )
    treeview = gtk.TreeView(model)

    #Password column
    renderer = gtk.CellRendererText()
    renderer.set_property('cell-background', '#efefef')
    renderer.set_fixed_size(120,20)
    renderer.connect("edited", self.on_cell_edited, model)
    renderer.set_data("column", COLUMN_PSW)
    column = gtk.TreeViewColumn("Password", renderer, text=COLUMN_PSW,
                           editable=COLUMN_EDITABLE)
    treeview.append_column(column)
```

Now any one suggest me for this problem, what i do

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to connect to the `editing-started` signal of the text renderer and set the `visibility` property of the GtkEditable to `False` in the handler. To avoid displaying the password when the user has finished editing it you should set the `text` property to a fixed string and clear the contents of the editable in the `editing-started` handler.

```
def on_cell_edited_started(self, cell, editable, path):
    editable.delete_text(0, -1)
    editable.set_visibility(False)
```

and then in `__init__`

```
self.renderer.set_property("text", "*****")
self.renderer.connect("editing-started", self.on_cell_editing_started)
```

**Update:**

I cannot reproduce your problem with the text showing after the `***`. I've modified your code as follows. when I click to edit the text is cleared and when I finish editing it goes back to `***`

*Callbacks:*

```
def on_cell_editing_started(self,cell, editable, path):
    editable.delete_text(0,-1)
    editable.set_visibility(False)
def on_cell_edited(self, renderer, path, new_text, model):
    iter = model.get_iter(path)
    model.set_value(iter, COLUMN_PSW, new_text)
```

*Setting up the renderer:*

```
    # psw column
    self.renderer = gtk.CellRendererText()
    self.renderer.connect("editing-started", self.on_cell_editing_started)
    self.renderer.connect("edited", self.on_cell_edited, model)
    self.renderer.set_property("text", "***")
    column = gtk.TreeViewColumn("Password", self.renderer ,editable=COLUMN_EDITABLE)
    treeview.append_column(column)  
    sw.add(treeview)
    self.show_all()
```

Everything else is as in the latest file you shared. I suspect you've somehow set the `text` property of the renderer with `set_property` and also bound a column to it as well. I'm going to be off-line for the next 10 days or so, if your still having problems have a careful read of the documentation and double check you code so you understand what each line is doing.

Comment: It's not working. if I give set_visibility as a False then I am not able to see or write in it. any other idea you have like a set_property, just let me know.

Comment: Are you sure you called `set_visibility` and not `set_visible` According to the [documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gtkentry.html#method-gtkentry--set-visibility) `set_visibility` should set the entry for password entry. If you could post the code you tried that would help.

Comment: Hi Phillip, I have tried all the way but it's not working.I have shared my code here just you check it and let me know. [Download File](https://www.opendrive.com/files?OF8yMDk0ODg0MF9nd0lzQw).

Comment: That file doesn't have the code for the `editing-started` callback :-(

Comment: I have changed the code, but It is showing, self.renderer is not attribute 'set_visibility'. Please check the code, I have written 'connect' signal in password column [Download corrected file](https://www.opendrive.com/files?OF8yMTAwMTcyOV9yMVA5Tw), I have struggled more over this problem. Please give me solution.

Comment: It should be `editable.set_visibility(False)` not `cell.set_visibility(False)` in the callback as the editable is the GtkEntry not cell which is the GtkRendererText

Comment: Thanks Phillip, Half part resolved at the time of editing it is correct but after editing i m assigning typed value to text box again for display so it is showing again character. edited time editable `entry` is not coming. see this function for edited `renderer.connect("edited", self.on_cell_edited, model)` and `model` is nothing but `liststore`.so tell me what i do now.

Comment: You want to just set the `text` property of the renderer to a fixed string. To do this get rid of `text=COLUMN_PSW,` when you create the column and instead do `renderer.set_property("text" "*****")`. That way you don't display the password but a different (fixed) string when the user finishes editing but still store the password in the listview with the `edited` handler.

Comment: actually editing time password is coming confidential but after editing it is not showing confidential and if I give temporary `renderer.set_property("text" "*****")`. it will show `"*****"` like that but if again i edit password then it will take like that `"****cd"`. And i want to chat with you, if u can do please let me know.

Comment: I'm going offline for a while, I've added some more info to my answer, I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The following is an anwser to the above question but using the language c#.

I did some investigation and found on [the gtkmm documentation page](https://docs.huihoo.com/gtkmm/gtkmm-2.4/tutorial/html/sec-treeview-examples.html) the following code

```
void ExampleWindow::cellrenderer_validated_on_editing_started(
    Gtk::CellEditable* cell_editable, const Glib::ustring& /* path */)
{
   //Start editing with previously-entered (but invalid) text, 
   //if we are allowing the user to correct some invalid data. 
   if(m_validate_retry)
   {
      //This is the CellEditable inside the CellRenderer. 
      Gtk::CellEditable* celleditable_validated = cell_editable;

      //It's usually an Entry, at least for a CellRendererText:
      Gtk::Entry* pEntry = dynamic_cast<Gtk::Entry*>(celleditable_validated);
      if(pEntry)
      {
         pEntry->set_text(m_invalid_text_for_retry);
         m_validate_retry = false;
         m_invalid_text_for_retry.clear();
      }
   }
}
```

It states that the underlying editable can be casted into an gtk entry. Using this entry you can easily set the visibility to false and the invisible char to "*".

So to get everything together:

- Set the celltextrenderer to a default string "***" on init
- hook the event editing started

  - inside the handler cast the editable to the gtk entry
  - clear the gtk entry
  - set the visibility to false on the entry
  - set the invisible char to "*"
- hook the event edited

  - extract the new value and store it.

Below the solution in c#:

```
// INIT
_textRenderer = new CellRendererText();
_textRenderer.Editable = true;
_textRenderer.EditingStarted += TextEditingStarted;
_textRenderer.Edited += TextEdited;
_textRenderer.Text = "***";

private void TextEditingStarted(object o, EditingStartedArgs args)
{
  if (args.Editable is Entry entry)
  {
    entry.InvisibleChar = '*';
    entry.Visibility = false;
    entry.Text = string.Empty;
  }
}

private void TextEdited(object o, EditedArgs args)
{
   var s = args.NewText;
   Console.WriteLine($"Password is {s}");
}
```